# elsa-cas class comma before figures

Tags: graphics, floats, elsarticle

I am not a latex expert and I am not really familiar with stack exchange, hence I apologise for any possible error. I am writing an article and I am using the els-cas template. I am not able to remove the comma I observe every time I insert a figure (on the upper left side).
Here, a short working example of my code that should reproduce the issue.
As I could not upload one of my figures I chose test as https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0c/F%28x%29_%3D_x%5E3_%E2%88%92_9x.PNG/250px-F%28x%29_%3D_x%5E3_%E2%88%92_9x.PNG.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-sc}


\usepackage[numbers,longnamesfirst]{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{placeins}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}


\begin{document}
\FloatBarrier
\begin{figure}[h]

\centering
\includegraphics[width= 0.5\textwidth]{test.png}


\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I'm not sure I fully understand your question. When I try your code I get an error `! LaTeX3 Error: The key 'cas/fig/h' is unknown and is being ignored`. When I remove the `[h]` the code compiles normally, and I don't see a comma anywhere in the output. Do you get the same error message, or not? Does it work for you when you remove the `[h]`? Note: as an image I used `\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}`, this is (as the name suggests) an example image that comes pre-installed with LaTeX and is therefore always available,

Comment: for everybody that has LaTeX installed, so it is convenient to use for questions here on the site for example, without needing to upload or download any additional image files.

Comment: Dear Marijin, you are right: the [h] is at the origin of the comma I see. Solved. Thank you.